# Content negotiation in WEB API without DataContract

Tags: asp.net-web-api, content-negotiation

How do I make HttpResponseMessage follow xml schema rather then datacontract?

i tried to do

```
return new HttpResponseMessage()
{
     StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
     Content = new ObjectContent<Foo>(foo, Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter)

};
```

but that did not do the trick.

Also if I do this, Action would always serve xml and would not do content negotiation. I tried to add List as a param, but HttpResponseMessage does not expect a list, just a single item.

Is there a way to allow content negotiation without use of DataContract? Basically now HttpResponseMessage is ignoring xml schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer to this is to use

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```